# Force a child class to initialise a parent property after computation

Tags: c#, oop

I have a child class `Bicycle` that inherits from `Agent`. The agent has a property which depends on the bicycle to define it. Namely, the physics model for the agent needs to be initialised with the velocity and acceleration constraints which are defined on a per-bicycle-basis and would be different for another type of agent.

The problem I have is that I cannot pass the parameters I need to calculate (the velocity/acceleration require calculations to draw them from a theoretical distribution) for this in the `base()` constructor because of course the child class hasn't yet been instantiated.

The calculations are done once per bicycle instance but are used multiple times so a simple static method won't do the job. I can just call a `protected` method in the parent after they're calculated but AFAIK there's no way to enforce this in the child, or more particularly in any future children which I might not write.

So for example, I could:

```
public abstract class Agent
{
    protected IPhysics PluginPhysics { get; set; }

    protected Agent(...)
    {
    }
}

public class Bicycle : Agent
{
    private double maxA;

    public Bicycle(Object anotherParameter) : base(...)
    {
        maxA = ComputationOfMaxA();
        this.PluginPhysics = new Physics(anotherParameter, maxA);
    }

    private static double ComputationOfMaxA()
    {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

or I could:

```
public abstract class Agent
{
    protected IPhysics PluginPhysics { get; private set; }

    protected Agent(...)
    {
    }

    protected void SetupPhysics(Physics physics)
    {
        this.PluginPhysics = physics;
    }
}

public class Bicycle : Agent
{
    private double maxA;

    public Bicycle(Object anotherParameter) : base(...)
    {
        maxA = ComputationOfMaxA();
        SetupPhysics(new Physics(anotherParameter,maxA));
    }

    private static double ComputationOfMaxA()
    {
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I'd rather not do either of those as there's no compile-time way to ensure that the child initialises `PluginPhysics` that I can think of, and I'd rather `PluginPhysics` not be able to be changed once it's been initialised. I'd also rather not have the parts of the parameters that need to go into `Physics`outside the `Bicycle` class. I appreciate that all these things might not be simultaneously possible.

So short of strongly worded documentation or a bunch of run-time null checks in the parent class before any of the relevant class objects are called on, is there an obvious C#-ish way I'm missing of *forcing* a child to initialise a parent class field before use if you **can't** do it in the constructor?

Comment: I tweaked your code a touch to make it more obvious you rely on ComputationOfMaxA to be complete before you create the physics object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[d4Rk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30685498/80274)  was very close, however you should try not call virtual methods from a constructor as [bad things can happen](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/641610/Be-Careful-with-Virtual-Method). However if you use a combination of Lazy loading tricks and [`ISupportInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can defer the creation of the plugin till after the constructor is finished.

```
public abstract class Agent : ISupportInitialize
{
    private bool _initialized = false;

    private IPhysics _pluginPhysics;
    protected IPhysics PluginPhysics 
    { 
        get
        {
            if(!_initialized)
                EndInit();
            return _pluginPhysics;
        }
    }

    protected Agent(...)
    {
    }

    protected abstract IPhysics CreatePhysics();

    ISupportInitialize.BeginInit()
    {
       //We make this a explicit implementation because it will not
       //do anything so we don't need to expose it.
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        if(_initialized)
            return;

        _initialized = true;
        _pluginPhysics = CreatePhysics();
    }
}

public class Bicycle : Agent
{
    private double maxA;
    Object _anotherParameter;

    public Bicycle(Object anotherParameter)
    {
        _anotherParameter = anotherParameter;
    }
    protected override IPhysics CreatePhysics()
    {
        ComputationOfMaxA();
        return new Physics(anotherParameter, maxA);
    }
}
```

The user of your class will need to call `EndInit()` after they get a object back to cause the `IPhysics` object to be created, however if they forget to call the initialize function the getter on the physics object will trigger the initialize call itself the first time it is used.

You could do everything I have shown without the `ISupportInitialize` interface and just having a public `Initalize()` method on the base class but I like to expose framework interfaces when they fit.

Comment: This is more elegant than the sort of null checking I was thinking of as it uses a proper interface which is explicitly for initialising "co-dependent properties" which is essentially what I have here. It certainly feels the most 'C#ish'. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about enforcing the subclass to implement a `CreatePhysics` method, and call this in the base ctor?

Like this:

```
public abstract class Agent
{
    protected IPhysics PluginPhysics { get; private set; }

    protected Agent(...)
    {
        var physics = CreatePhysics();
        SetupPhysics(physics);
    }

    void SetupPhysics(IPhysics physics)
    {
        this.PluginPhysics = physics;
    }

    protected abstract IPhysics CreatePhysics();
}

public class Bicycle : Agent
{
    private double maxA;

    protected override IPhysics CreatePhysics()
    {
        ComputationOfMaxA();
        return new Physics(maxA);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great so long as the Physics plugin doesn't also need things that come in through the Bicycle constructor ... which unfortunately is my case. I might update the question given this.

Comment: In general it is frowned upon to call a abstract/virtual class in the constructor. This is because child constructors will not have began to run yet and class level variables will not have been instanced yet, when you have more than one level of inheritance this can get quite tricky to manage.

Comment: However, if you combine this method with [`ISupportInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you have `EndInit()` call `CreatePhysics()` everything will be fine.

Comment: Thx for the hint @ScottChamberlain I'll take a look at it, and will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

How about making the constructor for `Agent` take the `IPhysics` object and making it `protected` Then in your `Bicycle` class, you are forced to call the constructor on the base which sets up your class property:

```
public class Agent
{
    protected IPhysics PluginPhysics { get; private set; }

    protected Agent(IPhysics physicsPlugin) 
    {
        PluginPhysics = physicsPlugin;
    }
}

public class Bicycle : Agent
{
    public Bicycle(IPhysics physicsPlugin)
        : base(physicsPlugin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bicycle ctor");
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do you perform the calculations for `physicsPlugin`?

Comment: I might end up coming to this. What I'm trying to avoid is certain things that need to go into that physicsplugin constructor from being outside the Bicycle class. Though I appreciate that wasn't in the question, which I've now updated.

Comment: If you don't want those parts outside the Bicycle class, then why not keep everything internal to the `Agent`? I guess I'm a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @DavidG The maxV calc would be unique to the `Bicycle` type compared to say, a `Car` (which would have a different calc for it's maxV); they would both be types of `Agent`. The main part of the program passes in (for e.g.) an initial speed to the `Bicycle` constructor but ideally doesn't know what actual physics plugin is being used; that information would live in the `Bicycle` (a `Car` might use a different plugin). One could therefore change out the plugin inside the `Bicycle`  without needing to pass anything different in to the `Bicycle` constructor. If that makes any sense.